# Multi Threading Non Atomic Operations With Atomic

Tags: multithreading, assembly

I was wondering if this scenario was possible or does the CPU make an guarantees that this won't happen at such a low level:

Say there is a value that is misaligned and requires 2 fetches to get the whole value (32 bit value misaligned on 32-bit system). So both threads are only executing one instruction, thread 1 a mov that is reading from memory and thread 2 an atomic mov that is writing to memory.

- Thread 1 fetches first half of Value
- Thread 2 atomically writes to Value
- Thread 1 fetches second half of Value

So now on Thread 1 will contain 2 halfs of different values.

Is this scenario possible or does the CPU make any guarantees that this won't happen ?

Comment: What architecture are you talking about? They're all vastly different when it comes to atomicity. Though, I don't know of any systems which have a atomic stores to unaligned addresses.

Comment: Sure this is possible, it will happen when the value straddles an L1 cache line.  With, say, two bytes in one cache line and two bytes in another.  Atomic reading or writing such a value is not possible.

Proper alignment is required to avoid this.  Almost never a problem in a compiled language since the compiler picks the address, certainly possible in assembly.

Comment: Also with 8-bit architectures. Byte writing/reading is usually atomic. In interrupt the the 16-bit store is often atomic - interrupts disabled.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my non-expert anwser...

It is rather complex to make misaligned accesses atomic, so I believe most architectures don't give any sort of guarantee of atomicity in this case. (I don't know of any architecture that can do atomic misaligned fetches, but they just might exist. I don't know enough to tell.)

It's even complex just to fetch misaligned data; so architectures that want to keep things really simple don't even allow misaligned access (For example the very "RISC-y" old Alpha architecture).

It might be possible on some architectures to do it by somehow locking (or protecting, see below) two cache lines simultaneously in a local cache, but such things are AFAIK usually not available in 'user-land', i.e. non-OS threads.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load-link/store-conditional for the modern way to achieve load-store (i.e. NOT tear-free read of two misaligned areas) atomicity for one (aligned) *word*. Now if a thread was somehow allowed to issue two *connected* (atomic) 'protect' instructions like that, I suppose it could be done, but then again, that would be complex. I don't know if that exists on any CPU.